# Windows 8 Pro version info in registry?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, version

For Windows 8 Pro, what is listed as version information in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion`?

(screen shot would be OK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CurrentVersion, I have the following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion]
"SystemRoot"="C:\\Windows"
"SoftwareType"="System"
"RegisteredOwner"="David"
"InstallDate"=dword:5118da08
"CurrentVersion"="6.2"
"CurrentBuild"="9200"
"RegisteredOrganization"=""
"CurrentType"="Multiprocessor Free"
"InstallationType"="Client"
"EditionID"="Professional"
"ProductName"="Windows 8 Pro"
"ProductId"="xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
"DigitalProductId"=hex:a4,00,00....
"DigitalProductId4"=hex:f8,04,00...
"CurrentBuildNumber"="9200"
"BuildLab"="9200.win8_gdr.130531-1504"
"BuildLabEx"="9200.16628.amd64fre.win8_gdr.130531-1504"
"BuildGUID"="ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff"
"PathName"="C:\\Windows"
```

(I've removed the `ProductId` value and truncated the long hex values for `DigitalProductId` and `DigitalProductId4`, as I assume they are not of interest.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the equivalent details for Windows 8.1 - just in case they're of interest:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion]
"SystemRoot"="C:\\Windows"
"SoftwareType"="System"
"RegisteredOwner"="..."
"InstallDate"=dword:52527488
"CurrentVersion"="6.3"
"CurrentBuild"="9600"
"RegisteredOrganization"=""
"CurrentType"="Multiprocessor Free"
"InstallationType"="Client"
"EditionID"="Professional"
"ProductName"="Windows 8.1 Pro"
"ProductId"="xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
"DigitalProductId"=hex:a4,00,00,...
"DigitalProductId4"=hex:f8,04,00,...
"CurrentBuildNumber"="9600"
"BuildLab"="9600.winblue_rtm.130821-1623"
"BuildLabEx"="9600.16384.amd64fre.winblue_rtm.130821-1623"
"BuildGUID"="ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff"
"PathName"="C:\\Windows"
```